# Why won't SQL Server CE for WebMatrix 3 allow me to manually add a row to a table in my database?

Tags: database, sql-server-ce, primary-key, webmatrix

I haven't had this problem until I first tried to manually add data to a database since my upgrade to WebMatrix 3, so I don't know if this is a bug or some kind of fault prevention.

I have defined a very simple table with the primary key as `int` and set it to not allow nulls, and be of the type `IsIdentity` so that the int value will automatically increment, as needed.

A pic of that is shown here:

[image]

Okay, seems simple enough, but when I try to manually add data to the table, it, as it should, does NOT allow me to modify the primary key value in any way (because it is automatic).

All I do is put in a couple of string values to the `type` and `location` columns and it tells me that it couldn't commit changes to the database because of the invalid value in the primary key field (it acts as though it is gonna try to throw `NULL` in as the value, but this should be overridden when it automatically adds the row. The user-interface does not allow me to control or edit this value in anyway).

A pic of this is shown here:

[image]

What is this? Some kind of bug? Is it a new rule that WebMatrix does not allow a developer to add values to the database manually? Do I have to write a query every time I want to add something to the database? Am I in the Twilight Zone? (Okay, sorry about the last one...)

Also, I've noticed that if I don't have `IsIdentity` set, I can edit the field, put a PERFECTLY VALID integer therein, and it still errors the same way, so I use `ESC` to backup my changes, then hit refresh, only to find that it did, indeed, add the row anyway :/ . So, this interface seems kind of buggy to begin with. In my scenario above (using `IsIdentity`), it DOES NOT add the row anyway, unfortunately.

--------------------UPDATE--------------------------

I just recently downloaded a WebMatrix update, and it appears that they have fixed this! Yay! (till now I was just querying generic INSERT INTO statements and editing them manually from there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the SQL CE tooling with WM3 is broken, suggest you look at other tools for editing data - I can recommend the standalone SQL Server Compact Toolbox (disclosure: I am the author)

Comment: Well, I appreciate the response. I was hoping this wasn't the case, but I really didn't see how it could be much else. I have used the SQL Server Compact Toolbox before, and it seems I will be using it again :)  Nice program, it helped me out quite a bit before.

Comment: Actually I have used that toolbox before (it REALLY helped me out). It allowed me to take a third party database exported from Access as a CSV file, and import it into SQL Server CE. Thanks, man!